# Getting all vertices of a rectangle

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl

In my program, I had a requirement to plot a rectangle that that is prependicular to a line coming from the centre.

To orient the rectangle in this way in 3D space, I used the `gluLookAt` giving it the lookAt point and plotted the rectangular figure. This worked correctly for me.

To draw the rectangle (in my framework, that uses openGL at the back), I now use a rectangle class and have extended it with a 3D `Node` (where node is something that has a `lookAt` point). Given width, height and the top vertex, the rectangle is drawn (node is at the top left vertex and orients the rectangle using lookAt).

`Node` also has a `getPosition()` function that gives me its 3D position (top left in rectangle - say 300,400,20). I am trying to get the position of the **other three vertices** in 3D space to use for my operation. Since the rectangle is oriented in 3D space, other three vertices can't just be fetched by addition of width and height. With the rectangle oriented in 3D, how do I get the position of the other three vertices?

Comment: How can a rectangle be perpendicular to something?

Comment: The OP probably refers to the rectangle's normal vector

Comment: @Kos is right about the normal vector thingy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retreive the position of the 3 other points using the normal of the rectangle. In order to orient a rectangle in space, you need 2 information:

- its position, commonly represented as a 3 or 4 components vector, or a 4x4 matrix ;
- its orientation, commonly represented as a quaternion.

If you have the orientation represented with a normal, and only have one point, you just *can’t* deduce the other points (because you need another information to solve the rotation equation around the normal). I think the best idea is to use quaternion to orient things in space (you can still retreive the normal from it), but you can also use a normal + one vector from the rectangle. You said you only have one point, and a tuple (width,height), so the common method based on the × operation won’t make it through.

I suggest you to:

- make your `Node` class a class that correctly handles orientation; `lookAt` isn’t designed for that job ;
- combine the translation matrix (position) with a cast matrix from the quaternion (orientation) to correctly handle both position and orientation ;
- use that matrix to extract a rotated vector you’ll used like `rotated × normal` to get the 3 points.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum amount of coordinates is just slightly less than 9: that's three vertices of a generic rectangle in 3d-space (Ax,Ay,Az, Bx,By,Bz, Cx,Cy,Cz).

The last one is e.g. D=A+(B-A)+(C-A)=B+C-A.

Why it's slightly less, is that any triplet of A,B,C coordinates do not necessarily form a 90 degree angle -- but it really doesn't make much sense to pursuit for the simplistic possible arrangement and be prepared to calculate cross-products or normalize vectors.

```
 A----B
 |    |
 C---(D)
```

EDIT: Vector arithmetic primary:

To Add / Subtract vectors, one sums the elements.
 A=B+C means (ax = bx+cx; ay=by+cy; az=bz+cz).

Dot product in (any dimension) is the sum of product of terms:
 dot(A,B) = ax*bx + ay*by + az*bz;  // for 2,3,4, any number of elements/dimensions.

[Cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) is a special operator that is well defined at least in 2 and 3 dimensions. One of the geometric interpretations of cross product is that it produces a vector that is perpendicular to both vectors of it's parameters.

If A is a vector (ax,ay,az), it also means a direction vector from origin O=(0,0,0) i.e. A = A-O = (ax-0,ay-0,az-0);
Likewise (B-A) is a [direction] vector from A to B (sometimes written as AB (with an arrow --> on top))

One can 'add' these directed vectors e.g. as:

```
    o----->
           \
            \
      <------o
     /
    /
   x
```

And so, if one adds the vector A+(B-A) + (C-A), one ends to the point D.

Comment: I am not fully what this meant but does that mean the three points can be found by cross product of vectors etc.?

Comment: Yes. If you have 'normal' vector of a plane and a right vector (B-A) that are orthogonal (i.e. their dot product is zero), then down/up vector (C-A) is the cross-product of the two and D=B+C-A again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It would be great if you could expand the answer to add more details with the terminology of `C-A`, `B+A` and the mathematics to get the coordinates, since I am not really experienced with openGL

Comment: Have a read on the basics of linear algebra. It will be difficult to continue graphics programming without that.

Comment: FYI a rectangle in 3-space has 8 degrees of freedom (3 for translation, 3 for rotation, and 2 to scale it), so you do need at least 8 ordinates to constrain it. The extra one just makes the constrainment more uniform, so there is less computation each time you want to use it.